# Scraping dates from twitter in R?

Tags: r, date, twitter, web-scraping

I have found a bunch of guides on how to scrape tweets off of twitter using R however, I am interested in also getting the date and time of the tweet. Is there a way for me to do this? Is there a guide anyone can direct me to?

https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-use-r-to-scrape-tweets-super-tuesday-2016/

This is the guide I was using. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `rtweet` is a modern twitter API access package with plenty of documentation. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Twitter provides a column that is "timestamp", you can convert it easily to  a date-time format.

I got this format when I got the tweets:

```
1420121295000
```

and to convert it, I used:

```
dataset$time_stamp <- as.POSIXct( (as.numeric(dataset$time_stamp) * 0.001), tz = "America/Sao_Paulo", origin = "1970-01-01")
```

which got me:

```
01-01-2015 12:08:15
```